# chartjs dataset attribute hidden from function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm populating my datasets array with this code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    parsedData.push({
        label: custNameArray[i],
        data: [chartData[i]],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 142, 204, 1)",
        hoverRadius: 9,
        hidden: function(i) {
            if(Condition) {
                return true;
            }
        },
    });
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to set the hidden attribute dynamic with a function - but my approach seems to be wrong. How can I achieve that?

Best regards,
David

EDIT, adding the solution:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
     const hidden = chartData[i]["y"]<=yMin || chartData[i]["y"]>=yMax;
     parsedData.push({
       label: custNameArray[i],
       data: [chartData[i]],
       backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 142, 204, 1)",
       hoverRadius: 9,
       hidden,
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a function to hidden not the result of this function. But if Condition = true returns true. Why not just do `hidden: Condition` this will return the same result and doesn't require a function call. Other option would be this construction.

```
for(let i =0; i < chartData.length; i++){
 const hidden = Condition;
 parsedData.push({
   label: custNameArray[i],
   data: [chartData[i]],
   backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 142, 204, 1)",
   hoverRadius: 9,
   hidden  
})
```